# When I try to sync with Google Photos, it stops after a few photos

Tags: google-photos

I am using the Google Photos app on my OnePlus 3 android phone. Each time I open it, Photos starts backing up (e.g. "Backing Up - 734 photos left"). This number will drop by 10 or 20 and then just stop. I have left it for a long time and it never changes. If I then close the app and open again, it will do another 10 or 20 and then stall again. So it is very slow and tedious. I am backing up to Google Drive, which has plenty of free room. Anything obvious I can do to fix?

I have posted on a Google forum but got no replies.

Comment: See if deleting the cache of Photos app helps

Comment: This happens to me too. It happens in Google Photos, Dropbox, etc. This is probably WiFi, and I believe it happens when WiFi gets re-directed from this task to something else which takes focus from this operation. If I monitor it manually, and continue to bring "focus" to the operation, it becomes less obvious, but clearly tedious; a long delay will cause the original connection to be unrecoverable until restarted. You want it, it'll be best to do it.